# Processing corn into hominy

Tags: corn, food-processing, hominy

I recently bought corn from a local co-op (blue flour corn), with the aim of turning it into masa. I nixtamalized the corn with an alkaline bath that I made from slaked lime. I used 1/4 cup of slaked lime per 10 cups of water. I had 1.8 gallons (30 cups) of water for 3 pounds of corn. After boiling the slaked lime into the water and letting it right for a bit, I added the corn and boiled for a while. Then I let it sit over night for 12-14 hours before rinsing and drying. The corn turned the classic yellow color of hominy (at the ends, it was blue corn) and it smelled of hominy. However, most of the corn didn't puff up to the size of dried hominy you'd buy in a store. Any clues to why this might be?

Comment: Much commercial whole-kernel hominy is made from special corn varieties with gigantic kernels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely that you didn't boil/cook long enough...or didn't include a rinse then cook step after the initial boil. It sounds like you were closer to nixtamalized corn used to make masa.  Hominy requires further cooking so that the kernels are fully hydrated and cooked through.